# Parse xml response and display it to main screen in blackberry

Tags: java, parsing, blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I have following kind of xml response from some http://url.com

```
<ArrayOfMovie>
   <Movie>
      <movieID>7</movieID>
      <name>Badmaash Company</name>
      <starCast> Shahid Kapoor, Anushka Sharma, Meiyang Chang, Vir Das </starCast>
      <releaseDate>2010-05-07</releaseDate>
      <moviePoster>bc/bc.jpg</moviePoster>
      <movieGenere>Drama</movieGenere>
   </Movie>
</ArrayOfMovie>
```

Now I want to parse this data and display it to blackberry main screen.

I have tried it using kxml and SAXParser. But unfortunately I couldnot parse it properly.

Can anybody help me to solve the above issue with some sample code or tutorial ?

Thanks in advance....

Comment: Without the code you did on in java we can't really help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following snippit of code should enable you to retrieve and parse XML from a URL.
It is very basic and has no real handling of potential errors.

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.microedition.io.*;
import net.rim.device.api.xml.parsers.*;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;

public class Test 
{

    public Document RetreiveXMLDocFromURL(String url) throws IOException
    {
        HttpConnection httpConn = (HttpConnection)Connector.open(url);
        int responseCode = httpConn.getResponseCode();
        Document xmlDoc = null;

        if (responseCode == HttpConnection.HTTP_OK)
        {
            try
            {
                InputStream inputStream = httpConn.openInputStream();
                DocumentBuilder docBuilder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
                xmlDoc = docBuilder.parse(inputStream);                 
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                //error handling
            }                               
        }
        else        
        {
            //error handling
        }

        return xmlDoc;
    }
}
```